# Handling physical buttons on Android

Tags: android

I'm creating a 2d game for android.I want to handle physical buttons on Android but what i have to do if i will handle these buttons from another class not from Activity.Because i'm using my own screen class based on opengl in my game and i want to handle menu buttons from different screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabActivity to switch between two different activities.

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated. It is encouraged to use the Android Support Package to implement tabs within an `Activity`.

Comment: TabActivity is meanness for my situation.I'm asking that how i can reach this functionality from a sub class.

Comment: You can not handle menu events in one activity from another. Maybe you can use a floating (context menu) for the opengl even if it takes full screen.